# Android sending JSON object to server gone wrong using retrofit2?

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit2, gson

I am trying to develop an program which allows you to send a JSON object to server and then read the object in order to store the data in the database, but I'm unable to achieve that. Here is my code, could you tell me where I am going wrong and how I could correct it?

Here is my `APIService`:

```
@POST("testingjson.php")
Call<Result> confirmOrder(
    @Body JSONObject productCart
);
```

Here is the `Result` class:

```
public class Result {
    private JSONObject cartProducts;

    public JSONObject getCartProducts() {
        return cartProducts;
    }

    public void setCartProducts(JSONObject cartProducts) {
        this.cartProducts = cartProducts;
    }
}
```

And finally this is the call of service on the `clicklistener` of an button:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
Call<Result> call=service.confirmOrder(Cart);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OrderPlaced",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

And here is the PHP code where it is sent in order to store the elements         to the database on the server:

```
<?php
$password="";
$user="root";
$database="shadowpets";
$host="localhost";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die('Unable to Connect');
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
    $jsonData=file_get_contents("php://input");
    $jsonString=json_decode($jsonData,true);
    try {
        foreach($jsonString['Order Summary'] as $cart) {
            $name=$cart['ProductName'];
            $price=$cart['ProductPrice'];
            $quantity=$cart['ProductQuantity'];
            $cost=$cart['ProductCost'];
            $seller=$cart['SellerId'];
            $stmt=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO sProducts(Name,Price,Quantity,Cost,Sellerid)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$name,$price,$quantity,$cost,$seller);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        $res['result']="data inserted";
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        $res['result']=$ex;
    }
    print_r (json_encode($res));
}
?>
```

Upon running the app I'm getting following error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:java.lang.illlegalStateException:Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was String at line 1 column 1 path$

Could anybody tell me where I am going wrong, and how I can rectify the mistake?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question has very poor content. You need to read this and modify it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That error tells you that your response is not a json object but rather a string. Double check the response sent by your php server and make sure it's not sending the whole json as a single string. That's the issue.

Comment: @Fred i'm kind new to android could you tell me how could i see what iam sending to the server??

Comment: From the error looks more like what you're receiving is not what you expect... you expect ``Result``, but it looks like the server is sending an entire string. Not json text.